# How to disable zoom effect on images in portfolio in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image, content-management-system, zooming, effect

When you scroll down, You'll see 6 portfolio images. 
When you hover on each of them, you'll get a zoom effect.

How do you turn this zoom effect off in code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `themes/raw/js` folder you have file `common.js`. In this file find lines

```
$('.thumb, .gallery-icon').epicHoverFadeZoom({
    overlayColor: udt_global_vars.thumb_rollover_color,             //Hex: #xxxx
    fontColor: udt_global_vars.thumb_rollover_text_color,           //Hex: #xxxx
    captionDirection: 'topToBottom',                                //String: caption slide in/out direction
    opacity: udt_global_vars.thumb_rollover_opacity,                //Integer: 0-1
    transitionSpeed: 600,                                           //Integer: transitions speed, in milliseconds
    easing: 'swing',                                                //String: easing method - see http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html
    padding: parseFloat(udt_global_vars.thumb_rollover_padding),    //Integer: padding
    mobileActive:false,                                             //Boolean: whether to activate/deactivate for mobile
    zoomFactor: parseFloat(udt_global_vars.thumb_rollover_zoom_factor), //Float: zoom factor
    rolloverLogo: udt_global_vars.rollover_graphic
});
```

and comment them, then try again.

Bassicaly the zoom effect is made by plugin jquery.epicHover-fadeZoom.js

Comment: But where exactly can i disbale it, because I dont want to ruin the code

Comment: Like I said you must edit `common.js` file and comment or delete all these lines, because there your zoom plugins is initialized.